# php.ini file not showing changes

Tags: php, plesk, centos5

Background: Default Media Temple (dv) 4, Centos 5.8, Plesk 11, FastCGI

Installed APC from source.

Adding `extension = "apc.so"` to `/etc/php.ini` does not show APC on phpinfo after httpd restart.

Adding `extension = "apc.so"` to `/var/www/vhosts/example.com/etc/php.ini`does show APC on phpinfo in example.com after restart.

How can I get it to work with `/etc/php.ini` so I do not need to enable per domain. Or is this required with FastCGI and if so how do I have it set to add automatically to new sites.

Comment: isn't the php.ini file in `/etc/apache2/php5.1/php.ini`

Comment: This is not really a programming question. Perhaps this would be better suited to [sf]...

Comment: check `phpinfo()` and `php -i` - php will tell you exactly which .ini files it's using and where they are.

Comment: Restrat your web server, make sure you are changing the correct .ini file, @Marc B pointed out how to know that

Comment: As noted in my post, I used phpinfo already and was already able to get it to work with using the domains specific php.ini file however it does not work when using the server /etc/php.ini file. So trying to determine why that is, if with fastcgi it only works on per domain or I need to restart something other than httpd. As for did I restart apache, as noted in my post I restarted httpd. Is that different than apache?

Comment: It says, "Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/" which is the main server php.ini file. But says "Loaded Configuration File:" shows the path to specific domain php.ini that I noted in my post. So while it should use data from the domain's php ini, still dont understand why it's not also using the main php.ini. Will try again and rather than restarting httpd will try restarting the whole server and see.